# Is it possible to get code coverage in Azure Devops without publishing the artifact?

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, cobertura

I am using cobertura as I need it for report files to publish, and it seems to use a different coverage strategy from the default coverage options so I can't compare the coverages from different reports. Because I use cobertura, it produces a report file that I don't want showing up as an artifact when the pipeline runs in my target branch (I do use it for PRs). I just want the percentage posted to the build. How can I get that without the report being published as an artifact?

I have this problem, essentially: [Azure Devops Code Coverage falsly recognised as artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967282/azure-devops-code-coverage-falsly-recognised-as-artifact)

However, the solution is not applicable to me because when I select my repository and build artifact for a release, it just tells me that "Code Coverage" and "drop" were the last two artifacts to be produced by my build. I can't set a filter or choose one specific folder.

Comment: Just a note that I am also having the issue with phpunit - I output cobertura since Azure only recognizes Jacoco and Cobertura, and when doing so, it publishes these files that I do not want.. I just want the coverage percentage to be set.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the Azure DevOps logging commands and add the generated file as attachment?

[Publish code coverage using .coverage file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265028/publish-code-coverage-using-coverage-file)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, unfortunately. .coverage files are published by default with no work or extra steps.